# probability of $Q$ winning more then $P$

Tags: probability

Two hunters $P$ and $Q$ set out to hunt ducks. Each of them hits as often as he misses when shooting at ducks. Hunter $P$ shoots $50$ ducks and Hunter $Q$ shoots at $51$ ducks. Then the probability that $Q$ bags more ducks then $P$, is

what i try

probability of hunter $P$ shooting a targrt is $50/101$

probability of hunter $Q$ shooting a target is $51/101$

did not understand how to resolve it help me to solve it thanks

Comment: No, you are told that P *did* shoot at 50 ducks, and that Q *did* shoot at 51.

Answer (score 2):

We can reason this out rather simply.  Suppose that both $P$ and $Q$ shoot first at $50$ ducks.  There are three possible outcomes:

- $P$ hits more ducks than $Q$.
- $Q$ hits more ducks than $P$.
- $P$ and $Q$ hit the same number of ducks.

Let the probability of the third outcome be $r$.  By symmetry (since both hunters are equally likely to hit their targets), the first two outcomes must have equal probability, which is $\frac{1-r}{2}$.

Now, let $Q$ shoot at a $51$st duck.  The only way this can affect the probability we want (the probability that $Q$ hits more ducks than $P$) is if they were previously tied, and $Q$ hits the duck.  Since we are told that both hunters hit their target with probability $1/2$, the new probability that $Q$ leads $P$ after the last duck is shot at is

$$
P(\text{$Q$ strikes more ducks than $P$}) = \frac{1-r}{2} + \frac12 \times r = \frac12
$$

Comment: Don't all of the home work for them.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I had my doubts about whether this was a homework problem, exactly because it doesn't feel like the usual kind of normal approximation problem, and a relatively simple argument succeeds where arduous computation fails (or at least is excessively arduous).  I figured it was a puzzle.  But I suppose you might be right.